# Check if a payment method is online or offline

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, payment

Is there a way to check from the payment model instance (or anywhere else) if a payment method is offline or online?
Is there such a flag, or method?
I'm not talking about a specific method, I'm talking about all of them.

Comment: `Magento\Payment\Model\MethodInterface::isOffline()` isn't what you're looking for?

Comment: Damn. I missed that. You are right. You might want to put this as an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please take a look at `Magento\Payment\Model\MethodInterface::isOffline()` :)